# RegEx - extract words with prefix @ or #

Tags: php, regex

If I have a string

```
This is a @really nice#day.
```

On **first pass** I should get as an output/result words `really` and `day` (results should not contain dots or any other punctuation signs, also you should not just match A-Z,a-z and everything else ignore because string could contain international characters so keep that in mind).

On **second pass** I should get out everything except those two words and punctuation for ex.

```
This is a nice
```

RegEx is done via `PHP`.

**EDIT:** @hochl
The problem with `([@#]\w+)` is that it doesn't catch international characters like `šđžćč` so `#dayš` is recognized only as `#day`.

Comment: Is this homework? Regardless, please post what you have tried so far.

Comment: No, I need to extract words with @ as locations and # as tags on a website I'm working on. I searched through SO but couldn't find this case, only negations with digits or substrings (not single character).

Comment: See my second sentence. I'm not trying to pick on you, but by showing your effort, more people would be happier to help :) So help us help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To catch the international characters, you could use the following:

```
[@#]\p{L}+
```

You would need to use the unicode modifier `/u` for this to work in php.

Note:

- The `\p{L}` is telling it to match unicode "letters"
- You don't need to wrap the whole thing in parentheses `()` as the whole match is always the first group

Comment: `preg_match_all('/[@#]\p{L}+/u', $query, $results)` it is. Thanks.